# Sort list based on group count

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I'd like to sort a `List` on element *counts* of `IGrouping`s.

And that's it, the list should ideally be the same.  I would compromise with a new list, but then the elements should be the very same original objects, not copies (however shallow) and definitely not anonymous objects.

**Specifically:** We have an entity with many properties, and a list of objects of this type.  We'd like to **(1)** group the objects by certain properties (name, address, ...) then **(2)** count the number of elements in each group. Finally we'd like to **(3)** reorder the list based on these counts by placing the elements that are part of the larger groups first.

**Note:** Our main issue is that we can't seem to find a way to keep a reference to the original objects in the elements of the groups. Indeed all we can select in the Linq query is the grouping key (or properties of the key) and nothing else is exposed by `IGrouping`. We can't figure out how to associate a group element with an element of the list either, short of looking at the data (and even then, we'd need the primary key, which we can't add to the grouping key or it would defeat the purpose of the grouping to begin with).

Comment: instead of writing text, just write down a sample class with sample properties, and then tell us, by which properties you want to group and finally in what order you want to select

Comment: What you might be missing is that your `IGrouping` is actually also an enumerable of the items in that group. Thus once you have your groupings ordered its just a case of flattening your items into a single list again.

Comment: @ManishMishra: personally I don't think a class is necessary here. Effectively the question applies to any class with a single property on it. What good would adding that do anyway?

Comment: giving exact scenario, with similar replica of the code, reduces guess work, and also, infuses excitement to directly write the working code. besides, c# appeals more to me, than english so..

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, they were surprisingly helpful given the confusion in the question.  This was indeed a big and fundamental misunderstanding on my part, I explain in another answer.

Comment: @ManishMishra: Here you go. ;-) `class TestClass { public string TestString {get; set;} }`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var mySortedList = myList.GroupBy(x => x.Name).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                       .SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost no operation in .NET clones an object. Neither deeply nor shallowly. LINQ also does not clone the elements it processes. Therefore, a simple LINQ query will work:

```
var oldList = ...;
var newList = (from x in oldList
               group x by something into g
               orderby g.Count()
               from x in g //flatten the groups
               select x).ToList();
```

This code copies *references* to the original objects. If you believe otherwise, you are probably misinterpreting what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is embarrassing.

My mistake was indeed based on a misunderstanding:

```
class Item
{
    internal string Value { get; set; }
    internal string Qux { get; set; }
    internal string Quux { get; set; }
}

var query = from i in list
            group i by new { i.Value, i.Qux } into g // Note: no Quux, no primary key, just what's necessary
            orderby g.Count() descending, g.Key.Value
            select new { // [1]
                Value = g.Key.Value,
                Qux = g.Key.Qux,
                // Quux?
            }
```

My bad assumption was that the selection at [1] was acting on individual records, much like SQL. Well, hopefully I can save someone who had the same assumption:  it is not.

It seems obvious now, but the selection acts on individual groups, and hence here a new object would be created for each group, not for each element.

My second mistake was in focusing on the key, wondering how one would "pass" other properties without using it.  I was also worried that we seemed to be required to make shallow copies of our objects.  Again this is based on the fact that we were clueless as to how the `IGrouping` is behaving:  since we didn't know we were selecting on the groups, we couldn't even create new objects for each element from the select.

The solution is definitely not impressive:

```
var query = from i in list
            group i by new { i.Value, i.Qux } into g
            orderby g.Count() descending, g.Key.Value
            select g;

foreach (var group in query)
{
    foreach (var item in group)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} [Original object? {3}]",
            item.Value,
            item.Qux,
            item.Quux,
            list.Contains(item));

    Console.WriteLine("-");
}
```

Output:

```
AAA Foo ... [Original object? True]
AAA Foo ... [Original object? True]
AAA Foo ... [Original object? True]
-
BBB Foo ... [Original object? True]
BBB Foo ... [Original object? True]
-
AAA Bar ... [Original object? True]
-
CCC Foo ... [Original object? True]
-
DDD Foo ... [Original object? True]
-
DDD Bar ... [Original object? True]
-
EEE Foo ... [Original object? True]
```

Indeed the `IGrouping` elements are the original elements. From there we can create a new list without any issue.

**Update:** I flatten the result set outside of the query mainly to be able to write the group separator to the console for demonstration purposes, but see Tim's and usr's answers to flatten inside the query using `SelectMany` (and equivalent Linq syntax).

Needless to say, this was another classic case of "we're in too much of a hurry, let's read some examples here and there and that'll be it", where the proper approach would have been to spend a little bit of time learning the fundamentals.  Linq is not SQL.

My apologies for the time you may have wasted trying to clear the confusion.  Hopefully someone else in a hurry might benefit from these mistakes now.

Comment: Hopefully you've seen Tim S.'s nice concise way of generating the sorted list. Its surprisingly tidy given how complicated the task sounds. :)

Comment: I have indeed, I wasn't too familiar with `SelectMany` before. Actually usr's answer is pretty much the same, his code translates to `SelectMany` as well. That's some fast-track learning. Still, 'should've made a better initial effort.

Comment: I'm less familiar with the query syntax and think it looks less readable personally which is why I referred to Tim's. But as long as you've learnt something then its all worthwhile. ;-)