# How to sort grouped list item in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a gropued list item. I want to sort the grouped list item. I have grouped list this,

```
var groupedStaff = SystemTaskStaff.GroupBy(s => s.StaffId).ToList();
groupedStaff.Sort();
```

I know this is very basic question. Please help me to sort this.

Comment: sort by what? sort each group items, or the groups?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani, sort by groupedStaff list item count

Comment: edited my answer. please have a look.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort list based on group count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517707/sort-list-based-on-group-count)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to sort groups by Item count:

```
groupedStaff.OrderBy(g=> g.Count()); // ascending
```

for descending order:

```
groupedStaff.OrderByDescending(g=> g.Count());
```

Comment: why downvote? he wants to sort by the count of each group